# Closed points of a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over the residue field and the fraction field of a valuation ring $R$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $(R, M)$ be a valuation ring with algebraically closed fraction field $k$. Let $L = R/M$ be the residue field of $R$; it follows that $L$ is algebraically closed. I would like to understand the following: Suppose $Z$ is an irreducible closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ defined by the homogeneous ideal $A \subset k[X_0, ..., X_n]$. Let $B = \pi\{ A \cap R[X_0, ..., X_n] \}$ where $\pi$ is the quotient modulo $M$. Let $W \subset \mathbb{P}^n_L$ be defined by $B$. Suppose $[\bar{a_0}:...: \bar{a_n}]$ is a closed point of $W$. Then I would like to know how one can prove that there exit $b_0, ..., b_n \in R$ (not all in $M$) such that $b_j + M = \bar{a_j}$  for each $0 \leq j \leq n$ and $[b_0:...: b_n]$ is a closed point of $Z$.

I am asking this question because I would like to understand the proof of the following result. 
In Mumford's *'Red book of schemes'*, Theorem 1 Chapter II Section 8, he proves:
For all closed subsets $Z \subset  \mathbb{P}^n_k$, there is a unique closed subset 
$W \subset  \mathbb{P}^n_L$ such that 
$$
\rho(Z(k)) = W(L),
$$ 
where $\rho: \mathbb{P}^n(k) \to  \mathbb{P}^n(L)$.

I am having similar issues with the proof as in [this MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577499/question-about-theorem-1-chapter-ii-8-from-mumfords-red-book). If someone could provide an alternative reference for this result or an explanation for the statement in the first paragraph, it would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let me first reformulate this question slightly. Set $S = \text{Spec}(R)$, denote $\eta \in S$ the generic point (with residue field $k$) and denote $s \in S$ the closed point (with residue field $L$). We may assume $Z$ is not only irreducible but also reduced as the question is about points. I assume that $A \subset k[X_0, \ldots, X_n]$ is exactly the set of homogeneous polynomials vanishing on $Z$. Thus we see that $A$ is a homogeneous prime ideal. The homogeneous prime ideal $A \cap R[X_0, \ldots, X_n]$ defines an integral closed subscheme $\overline{Z} \subset \mathbf{P}^n_R$ whose generic fibre is $Z$ and whose closed fibre is $W$. We are going to think of $\overline{Z}$ as a scheme over $S$. Picture:
$$
\overline{Z} \longrightarrow S
\quad\text{with}\quad
\overline{Z}_\eta = Z \quad\text{and}\quad \overline{Z}_s = W
$$
Denote $\xi \in Z = \overline{Z}_\eta$ the generic point. Clearly, $\xi$ is also the generic point of $\overline{Z}$. Denote
$w = [\overline{a}_0 : \ldots : \overline{a}_n]$ the closed point of $W = \overline{Z}_s$ given to us. Then we have a specialization
$$
\xi \leadsto w
$$
which maps to the specialization $\eta \leadsto s$ in $S$. What you are asking for is to show that there is a closed point $z$ of $Z = \overline{Z}_\eta$ and specializations $\xi \leadsto z \leadsto w$.

(Hints: Observe that a closed point of $Z$ always is a $k$-rational point because $k$ is algebraically closed and that a $k$-rational point of $\mathbf{P}^n_k$ is the same as an $R$-rational point of $\mathbf{P}^n_R$ by the valuative criterion for projective space, so this will give you the sequence $b_0, \ldots, b_n \in R$ not all in $M$ well defined up to a unit in $R$, which specializes to $[\overline{b}_0 : \ldots : \overline{b}_n]$ in the closed fibre.)

The existence of $z$ is a general fact about the topology of finite type morphisms of schemes! AFAIK this property in general was first discovered by Brian Osserman and Sam Payne in a paper entitled "Lifting tropical intersections". In the Stacks project you can find it [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/053U).

On the other hand, I am pretty sure that you don't need this result in order to prove the statement in Mumford's book. In fact, I just looked at his proof of this fact and it uses just a little bit of algebraic geometry (projections) and going down for finite morphisms to prove this particular case of the Osserman-Payne result (the proof is on the bottom of page 130 in my edition). So I urge you to stick to this case and read what Mumford wrote there.